# How to convert point to longtitude and latitude in arcgis android?

Tags: android, dictionary, arcgis

I want to convert point to longtitude and latitude , as a below code I have point :

```
mMapView.setOnSingleTapListener(new OnSingleTapListener() {


                @Override
                public void onSingleTap(float x, float y) {


                    callout.hide();

                    int[] graphicIDs = graphicsLayer.getGraphicIDs(x, y, 25);
                    if (graphicIDs != null && graphicIDs.length > 0) {
                        Graphic gr = graphicsLayer.getGraphic(graphicIDs[0]);
                        updateContent((String) gr.getAttributeValue("Rating"),
                                (String) gr.getAttributeValue("Title"));
                        Point location = (Point) gr.getGeometry();
                        callout.setOffset(0, -15);
                        callout.show(location, content);


                    }

                }
```

I have this variable `location` how to find out the longtitude and latitude , I already changed the longtitude and latitude to point as a below :

```
double mercatorX = longtitude* 0.017453292519943295 * 6378137.0;
double a = latitude * 0.017453292519943295;
double mercatorY = 3189068.5 * Math.log((1.0 + Math.sin(a))
        / (1.0 - Math.sin(a)));
```

please i need your comment ...

Comment: Then do the inverse. Math is not that hard when you're a programmer ;)

Comment: my mind is not working now ;) , please be soo awesome help me if you can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found it GUYS**

```
       mMapView.setOnSingleTapListener(new OnSingleTapListener() {


            @Override
            public void onSingleTap(float x, float y) {

                //Message.message(getApplicationContext(), "showLayer"+x +":"+y);
                callout.hide();



                int[] graphicIDs = graphicsLayer.getGraphicIDs(x, y, 25);
                if (graphicIDs != null && graphicIDs.length > 0) {
                    Graphic gr = graphicsLayer.getGraphic(graphicIDs[0]);
                    updateContent((String) gr.getAttributeValue("Rating"),
                            (String) gr.getAttributeValue("Title"));
                    Point location = (Point) gr.getGeometry();
                    callout.setOffset(0, -15);
                    callout.show(location, content);
                    callout.setContent(content);


                    Log.e("EROR", location+"");


                    SpatialReference sp = SpatialReference.create(SpatialReference.WKID_WGS84);
                    Point aux = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(location, mMapView.getSpatialReference(), sp);

                    Log.e("L","latitude="+aux.getX());
                    Log.e("L","longitude="+aux.getY());


                }

            }
```

this is for location variable but if someone want to know X and Y,
you can do this :

```
   mMapView.setOnSingleTapListener(new OnSingleTapListener() {


            @Override
            public void onSingleTap(float x, float y) {

                //Message.message(getApplicationContext(), "showLayer"+x +":"+y);
                callout.hide();



                int[] graphicIDs = graphicsLayer.getGraphicIDs(x, y, 25);
                if (graphicIDs != null && graphicIDs.length > 0) {
                    Graphic gr = graphicsLayer.getGraphic(graphicIDs[0]);
                    updateContent((String) gr.getAttributeValue("Rating"),
                            (String) gr.getAttributeValue("Title"));
                    Point location = (Point) gr.getGeometry();
                    callout.setOffset(0, -15);
                    callout.show(location, content);
                    callout.setContent(content);


                    Log.e("EROR", location+"");

                    Point p=mMapView.toMapPoint(x,y );
                    SpatialReference sp = SpatialReference.create(SpatialReference.WKID_WGS84);
                    Point aux = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(location, mMapView.getSpatialReference(), sp);

                    Log.e("L","latitude="+aux.getX());
                    Log.e("L","longitude="+aux.getY());


                }

            }
```

thanks ...